# SSIS: convert date to datetimestamp with specified time

Tags: sql, ssis, substring

I been researching how to convert a date string that I have in my flatfile with also specifying a time. I found results for converting through a derived column in SSIS using DT_DBTIMESTAMP. But in my situation, I need to add in a time of 9AM: 9:00:00.000 as well since the flat file source doesn't have it.

So in my situation, I have this example from the flat string:

```
5/9/80
```

I would like it to be in SSIS as the following 1980-05-09 9:00:00.000

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DATEADD("HH",9,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)((DT_STR,30,1252)(DT_DBDATE)([Create Date])))
```

[Create Date]= 5/9/80

Answer (score 1):

Use the Data Conversion to first change the date to the DT_DBTIMESTAMP then use a derived with the following in the expression;

```
DATEADD("Hh",9,[COLUMN])
```

Obviously changing the column to the one in your dataflow. This should add 9 hours onto the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEADD("Hh",9, (DT_DBDATE)("19" + SUBSTRING([col], 5, 2) + "-" + RIGHT("00" + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([col], 3, 2), "/", ""), 2) + "-" + RIGHT("00" + REPLACE(SUBSTRING([col], 1, 2), "/", ""), 2)))
```